# How to combine two query from the same table

Tags: mysql

I have two query and I want to combine them into one query and distinct the `name` of the `styles`. Basically I just want to get the styles of the `teacher` where he belong on `schools`, and the `styles` of the `organization` where the `school` belong.

This is my query each so far.

**STYLES Table**

[image]

**Query 1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM styles s
WHERE s.organization_id = (
    SELECT t.school_id 
    FROM teachers t 
    WHERE t.user_id = 4 
)
```

**Result 2**
[image]

**Query 2**

```
SELECT * 
FROM styles s, teachers t 
WHERE t.school_id = s.school_id 
    AND t.user_id = 4
```

**Result 2**
[image]

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Combined result of all styles based on the user_id.

Comment: you want to see:
Teacher + style + school ?

Comment: no.. query1 and query2 will be combined on one query.

Answer (score 1):

You are just lacking proper joins with your queries. Don't user old join styles, use `INNER JOIN`

For what I could see you have joined your `styles` table with `teachers` table by different columns. **One way to do it** would be a simple UNION like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM styles s
         INNER JOIN teachers t
               ON s.organization_id = t.school_id
 WHERE t.user_id = 4
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM styles s
         INNER JOIN teachers t 
               ON t.school_id = s.school_id 
 WHERE t.user_id = 4
```

**NOTE: ** Do not use `select *` use all named columns.